# jQuery - how to select a child div

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="123">
    <div id="456"></div>
</div>
```

How would I go about accessing the child div in this case, the one with the 456 id using jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a list of the easiest ways of selecting that:

```
$('#456');
$('#123 div');
$('#123 > div');
$('div div');
```

Basically, just use the CSS selector you'd use and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks, guess I just wasn't using common sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this.

```
outerDiv = $('#123');
$('#456',outerDiv);
```